# How do I use drag and drop in FormArray with ngx-dnd?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, formarray

I want to use [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) in Angular 5.

I have created a list of forms with `FormArray` and I want to reorganize them with [ngx-dnd](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-dnd).

Here is my code:

```
<div class="ngx-dnd-container" ngxDroppable [model]="formData.controls">
     <div class="ngx-dnd-item" ngxDraggable [model]="line" formArrayName="lines" *ngFor="let line of formData.controls; let i = index;">
         <div [formGroupName]="i"> 
            <textarea formControlName="linedescription"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code works fine if the user types into textarea after they drag and drop.

This code doesn't work if the user just drags and drops, in this case my form Array "lines" is the same as before the drag and drop changes the order.

How should I use ng-dnd with FormArray, and can I use a callback method for ng-dnd in my Component to execute something after "drop"?

Comment: Providing a working example (plunkr or other) might help help you

Comment: Ok @MathieudeLorimier :
Voici le lien de l'app ou tu peux reproduire ce que je décris à savoir : 

- Le changement n'est pas pris en compte lors du "drop" (les lines ne se réorganisent pas dans l'Array lines
- Le changement fonctionne après un drop SI le user type dans un textarea 

-> L'app : https://angular-xqhjug.stackblitz.io
-> Dans l'éditeur : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqhjug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I have the solution!

**1 - ngx-dnd events**

ngx-dnd library allows us to use many events: `drop()`, `drag()`, `over()`, `out()`, `remove()`, `cancel()`. ([Source](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-dnd/blob/master/projects/swimlane/ngx-dnd/src/lib/directives/ngx-droppable.directive.ts#L26))

So, you can call your own method in your component if an item is "dropped". For example:

*form.component.html*

```
<div (drop)="dropped($event)" 
     class="ngx-dnd-container" 
     ngxDroppable 
     [model]="formData.controls">
//...
```

*form.component.ts*

```
dropped(event) {
    alert('Ok drop is Done !')
}
```

**2 - Update FormArray**

The problem was here: our "drop action" didn't re-order the FormArray.

Angular's [FormArray class](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) exposes many methods to solve this problem. I chose the `reset()` method because we can pass a value as a parameter and update the entire FormArray.

```
reset(value?: any, options?: Object)
```

*Finally, update your method in your form.component.ts*

```
dropped(event) {
    let linesCopy = [];
    this.lines = this.form.get('lines') as FormArray;
    for(let line of this.lines.controls) {
        linesCopy.push(line.value);
    }
    this.lines.reset(linesCopy);
}
```

It works correctly now, you can see a complete working example and source code in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adh1wk?file=app%2Fsuper-form.component.html).

PS: Be careful to use only form class methods when you manipulate forms in Angular. Don't use JavaScript methods to push, remove, set value, etc. Use only [FormArray class](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) methods.